# COUNT function doesnt not work with ALL in dax

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have this measure setup to calculate percentage based on count of items in a column

```
Count % = 
Var PaymentCount = 
    COUNT(
        'Pos Payments'[payment_method_id]
    )
RETURN DIVIDE(
    PaymentCount,
    CALCULATE(
        PaymentCount,
        ALL('Pos Payments'[payment_method_id])
    )
)
```

The problem is that it is always 100% (or 1) and I noticed that the ALL function does not remove filters. I actually tested this same code but with SUM function on another column in the same table and it works fine. So I dont think it has anything to do with the data model and there are no blank rows in this particular column. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using variables in the wrong way.

After a variable is calculated, it's stored in memory as a constant. Then you are attempting to apply filters to the constant. Let's say, the count is 6, then your formula essentially becomes this:

```
Count % = 
Var PaymentCount = 6
    
RETURN DIVIDE(
    6,
    CALCULATE(
        6,
        ALL('Pos Payments'[payment_method_id])
    )
)
```

I hope you understand now why it does not work.

To fix it, create a measure instead of the variable:

```
PaymentCount = COUNT('Pos Payments'[payment_method_id])
```

Then, use it in your other measures:

```
Count % = DIVIDE(
    [PaymentCount],
    CALCULATE(
        [PaymentCount],
        ALL('Pos Payments'[payment_method_id])
    )
```